# React native calendar show current week only

Tags: npm, react-native, calendar

Code:

```
 <CalendarPicker
                    minDate={minDate}
                    weekdays={['Su', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'Th', 'F', 'S']}
                    todayBackgroundColor="#979797"
                    selectedDayColor='#ff6c19'
                    selectedDayTextColor='#FFFFFF'
                     textStyle={{
                       fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeue',
                       color: 'rgb(96,96,96)'
                     }}
                  />
    </View>
```

import CalendarPicker from 'react-native-calendar-picker'

I have implemented CalendarPicker in my project.It is working fine.CalendarPicker shows all days from current month.How do i change CalendarPicker to show current week only?any help will be appricated.thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can do that without changing the CalendarPicker itself. You are supposed to set the `minDate` and `maxDate` to disable selection of other dates, but always render the full calendar.

If you still want to show only one week, fork the `CalendarPicker` project and add this option.

Comment: @ViktorSeč.what is the option?

Comment: I mean you'll have to program the feature (option to render only one week) yourself as this is not supported in the library.

Comment: thanks for your info...

Comment: any updates on this question please ??